# Vector fields potential

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, vector-fields

$\mathbf F(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf i+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\mathbf j$ when the region D is $D=\mathbf R^2 \vert (0,0) $

How do I proof that the vector field F has no potential in region D.

I know that:

$F_1=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$ and $F_2=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

and after that $\frac{dF_1}{dy}=\frac{dF_2}{dx} = \frac{y^2-x^2}{(y^2+x^2)^2}$

Line integral over unit circle:

$\oint_C \mathbf F \cdot \mathbf {dr}$

what is F and dr in this case. Limit values are $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the line integral along the unit circle!